# How to access second "td" using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html document that I am trying to scrape. I have gotten to the "table" part of the document, but I cannot seem to access the "td" that I want. Here is an image of a part of the document looks like:
[image: portion of html document]

This is some of my code:

```
prePostBody.find("table", {"class": "tborder"}).find("tr", {"valign": "top"}).find("td")
print(prePostBody)
```

When I run my code, I get this:

```
<td class="alt2" style="border: 1px solid #D1D1E1; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px" width="175">
<div id="postmenu_2012213">
```

So my code is working, and it is finding the `"td"` with `class="alt2"`, but I want to be able to access the `class="alt1"` portion of the table. How would I do that?

Comment: Images are difficult to work with. Please consider to replace it with a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
prePostBody.find("table", {"class": "tborder"}).find("tr", {"valign": "top"}).find("td", {"class": "alt1"})
print(prePostBody)
```